# Numpy array of rank > 1 and one of dimensions == 0

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing a function that reads data from file into a multi-dimensional `numpy` array. Data is regularly structured in sense of dimension lengths, however, some dimensions may be missing, in which case, I would let the length of that dimension be `0`. So I have stumbled upon this behavior:

```
In [1]: np.random.random((3,3))
Out[1]: 
array([[ 0.59756568,  0.47198749,  0.23442854],
       [ 0.29374254,  0.58289927,  0.40497268],
       [ 0.00481053,  0.63471263,  0.90053086]])

In [2]: np.random.random((0,3,3))
Out[2]: array([], shape=(0, 3, 3), dtype=float64)
```

OK, so I get an empty array. This makes sense if I look at it as 2nd and 3rd dimensions are subset of the 1st, which is nil, and thus the whole array is nil. However, I would expect `np.random.random((3,3,0))` to be equivalent to `np.random.random((3,3))`. However,

```
In [3]: np.random.random((3,3,0))
Out[3]: array([], shape=(3, 3, 0), dtype=float64)
```

An empty array again.

Is this expected behavior? I understand the difference between `np.array((3,3))` and `np.array((3,3,1))` or `np.array((1,3,3))`, but I am looking for an explanation why does a dimension of length `0` degenerate the whole array and not only that dimension. Is it just me, or is this one of Python/numpy WTFs?

Comment: Surely it is becase the size of the array in the case of `np.random.random((3,3,0))` will be `3 x 3 x 0 = 0`?

Comment: @Chris Sure, but why would one even consider a 0-lenght dimension? Intuitively, I would expect exception handling in that case. Maybe I am looking at it the wrong way. I am hoping for an explanation why is a 0-lenght dimension taken into account when determining the size or shape of the array.

Comment: I agree, it seems like an oversight. But I guess it may be deliberate: rather than returning a 2D array when you specified three dimensions (principle of least astonishment?) it is returning a 3D array, not a particularly useful 3D array admittedly. Hopefully someone can chime in with a more enlightened answer.

Comment: I hit the same issue, and interestingly enough also trying to concatenate a multidimensional array from a file. It seems I have to set it to None and check the first time if it is None treat it differently. Did you find any better solutions?

Comment: @dashesy No, I have not, I remember implementing code to handle each case separately, but no general solution. Please post your example as an answer if you think it is relevant to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I state in a comment, you are getting an empty array because the size of an array is always zero if any of the dimensions are zero. Can I ask what you are trying to do? If you want an empty 3rd dimension you can try something like the following:

```
>>> x = numpy.random.random((3,3))
>>> y = x[..., numpy.newaxis]
>>> y

array([[[ 0.92418241],
        [ 0.76716579],
        [ 0.82485034]],

       [[ 0.30571695],
        [ 0.71012271],
        [ 0.54609355]],

       [[ 0.98192734],
        [ 0.25505518],
        [ 0.75473749]]])

>>> y.shape
(3, 3, 1)

>>> x.shape
(3, 3)
```